# How to use macros to repeat math equations in different settings

Tags: macros, equations

Suppose I have an equation like `y=a+b` that I want to repeat multiple times. I want to use macros to define this equation.

First, I thought that the following definition would do the tric.

```
\newcommand{\myEquation}{\ensuremath{y = a + b}}
```

But then I figured I might want to use this equation inside a `align` sometimes, so I need parameters. Then I tried :

```
\newcommand{\myEquation}[1]{
  \IfEqCase{#1}{
    {a}{\ensuremath{y = a + b}
    {b}{\ensuremath{y &= a + b}
  }[\PackageError{tree}{Undefined option to tree: #1}{}]
}
```

When I call this command with `\myEquation{a}`, I get the error message below.

```
Undefined control sequence. \myEquation{a}
Misplaced alignment tab character &. \myEquation{a}
Package tree Error: Undefined option to tree: a. \myEquation{a}
```

Can someone help me understand the problem here and what I should do ?

Thank you !

---

The following compiles without errors but the alignment is wrong.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amsthm}

\newcommand{\myFirstEquation}{y_1 = a + b}
\newcommand{\mySecondEquation}{2 y_2 = x}

\begin{document}

  \begin{align}
    \myFirstEquation \\
    \mySecondEquation 
  \end{align}

\end{document}
```

The following example compiles with the previous error message.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amsthm}

\newcommand{\myEquation}[1]{
  \IfEqCase{#1}{
    {a}{\ensuremath{2 y_3 = x}}
    {b}{\ensuremath{2 y_3 &= x }}
  }[\PackageError{tree}{Undefined option to tree: #1}{}]
}

\begin{document}

  \myEquation{a}

\end{document}
```

---

As suggested, I tried an example without the `\IfEqCase`. It works.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amsthm}

\newcommand{\myEquation}{\ensuremath{2 y_2 = x}}
\newcommand{\myEquationP}{\ensuremath{2 y_2 & = x}}
\newcommand{\otherEquation}{y_1 &= a + b}

\begin{document}

  \begin{equation}
    \myEquation
  \end{equation}

  \begin{align}
    \myEquationP \\
    \otherEquation
  \end{align}

\end{document}
```

Would be nice if the `\IfEqCase` worked too though. But I guess it will do !

Comment: Can you provide a complete minimal working example? Now, it is hard to tell where the error lies exactly.

Comment: Sometimes it's better not to wrap anything in a command, but in this case, I suggest a `starred/unstarred` version of your command, rather. And your example does not compile due to `\IfEqCase` is unknown

Comment: @Corathy: Your example is still missing `\usepackage{xstring}` ...

Comment: I did not get an error message saying that `IfEqCase`is unknown, that is probably why I could not fix it. Thank you, I edited my question. I now have a solution that works.

Comment: Why the `xstring ` package ? It works on my computer without it...

Comment: @Corathy : You've got another document than what you show us-- perhaps another package includes `xstring` then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an idea: pass the alignment operator `&` into the macro when you need it and `{}` otherwise. Keeps it simple.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\myeq[1]{2y_3 #1= x}

\begin{document}

\noindent Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, $\myeq{}$, consetetur sadipscing
elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna
aliquyam erat:
% don't leave a blank line here - see comment below by barbara beeton
\[ \myeq{} \]

Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est.

\begin{align}
\myeq{&} \\
y_1 &= a + b
\end{align}


At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita 
kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

\begin{align*}
    \myeq{&}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

To make it more symmetrical you could also use

```
\newcommand\myeq[1]{2y_3 #1 x}
```

and call either `\myeq{=}` or `\myeq{&=}`.

[image]

Comment: not really relevant to the answer (ingenious!), but a recommended practice -- don't leave a blank line before any display environment.  the spacing will always be wrong.  if you want to leave a visual clue in the input, put a `%` at the beginning of the otherwise blank line, and it will be treated as a comment (and ignored).